# WiX -- Set Component Directory at Install Time?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

The following doesn't compile, but how can I get the equivalent functionality of `[MYDIR]`?

```
<Component Id="MyComponent" Guid="MY_GUID" KeyPath="yes" Directory="[MYDIR]">
    <File Source="MyFile.dll" Name="MyFile.dll"/>
</Component>
```

(I'm trying to put the file `MyFile.dll` into a directory whose path is determined when the installer is actually run.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Directory` attribute must correspond to a `<Directory>` tag somewhere in your installer.  You can set that directory to the value of a property that gets set at runtime.  A good example of this is using the WixUI_InstallDir to ask the user where they want to install an application.

Here is an example of usage:  https://wixtoolset.org//documentation/manual/v3/wixui/dialog_reference/wixui_installdir.html